# Ranking with tiebreakers

Tags: c#, xna

How do I go about ranking a list based on one criteria, and then separating ties (of which there are likely to be a lot) based on another?

My (working) attempt to rank drivers based on their points totals.

```
for (int j = 0; j < career.NumberOfDrivers; j++)
        {
            int rank = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < career.NumberOfDrivers; i++)
            {
                if (career.driver[j].championshipPoints <   career.driver[i].championshipPoints)
                {
                    rank += 1;
                }
            }
            career.driver[j].championshipRank = rank;
        }
```

Presumably I then want to cycle through afterwards checking for ties - the problem is there are definitely going to be situations when I have several drivers tied on 0.

How do I go about simply breaking these tiebreakers alphabetically (ie based on first letter of driver's names)?

EDIT - my solution if its of interest. Pretty nasty hack in some respects but does the job.

```
        List<Driver> tempDriver = new List<Driver>();

        for (int i = 0; i < career.driver.Count; i++)
        {
            tempDriver.Add(career.driver[i]);
        }


        tempDriver.Sort(
        delegate(Driver d1, Driver d2)
        {
            if (d1.championshipPoints == d2.championshipPoints)
            {
                return d1.Name.CompareTo(d2.Name);
            }
            return d1.championshipPoints.CompareTo(d2.championshipPoints);
        }
        );

        for (int i = 0; i < career.NumberOfDrivers; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < career.NumberOfDrivers; j++)
            {
                if (career.driver[i].Name == tempDriver[j].Name)
                {
                    career.driver[i].championshipRank = j + 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make a comparator with all the tie-breaking conditions

Comment: If they have equal points then it would be unfair to rank them based on their names. Otherwise there would be a lot of drivers with names like Aaron Aardvark. Maybe you should adjust your program to allow for more than one driver with the same rank.

Comment: (Missed edit time window.) For display purposes, you could order them by the first or last to achieve the number of points, which would have some sort of meaning.

Comment: Hi - that isn't the actual tiebreaker. I just try to take anything non-essential out when I ask a question, and asking the question saying that driver's name is the tiebreaker allows people to answer the bit I'm interested in (ie how to sort with a tiebreaker) without having to fully explain the tiebreaking criteria (which is ultimately superfluous to the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Sort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your drivers List, using a delegate.
If drivers have same points number, return the comparison result of their names.
Else return the comparison or their points

```
driversList.Sort(
    delegate(Driver d1, Driver d2)
    {
        if (d1.championshipPoints == d2.championshipPoints)
        {
            return d1.name.CompareTo(d2.name);
        }
        return d1.championshipPoints.CompareTo(d2.championshipPoints);
    }
);
```

Then the ranking of a driver is simply its index in the sorted list.

Edit:

This solution has n*log(n) complexity (the OP first attempt is O(n^2) )

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something (and apologies if I am ) - but how would this solve the issue for a multiple tie?

Comment: They would be sorted alphabetically. But if you have another tie-breaking criteria you'd wish to add, insert it in the delegate.

Comment: Sorry - I meant between more than two drivers. Basically, after the first race, any driver who didn't score points is going to be tied in last on 0 (which will be 12 drivers)

Comment: Same, it will work. If three drivers have the same score, this method will sort them all by name. Don't let the delegate with "two" arguments fool you : this is a comparator. All elements of the list will end up sorted one relative to each other.

Comment: This worked - thanks. Bit of a hack in its current form but does the job for now! Cheers for help.